# Parsing JSON of IAP Receipt

Tags: ios, json, swift

I recently implemented receipt validation function for my app however I am having a hard time parsing the receipt. I am able to get the status of it by doing this

```
verifyStatus = json!["status"]
```

and then the 'receipt' and 'in_app' values from these respectively

```
let verifyItem2 = json!.objectForKey("receipt")
let verifyItem3 = verifyItem2!.objectForKey("in_app")
```

However, when I do the same for 'product_id'. I keep getting an error. Probably because the 'in_app' key has an extra set of parentheses before it. Some advice would be appreciated.

Example Receipt:

```
environment = Sandbox;
receipt =     {
    "adam_id" = 0;
    "app_item_id" = 0;
    "application_version" = 1;
    "bundle_id" = "xxxxxxxx";
    "download_id" = 0;
    "in_app" =         (
                    {
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2016-02-16 05:47:31 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1455601651000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-15 21:47:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000194125405;
            "product_id" = "xxxxxxxx";
            "purchase_date" = "2016-02-16 05:47:31 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1455601651000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-02-15 21:47:31 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000194122312;
        }
    );
    "original_application_version" = "1.0";
    "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
    "receipt_creation_date" = "2016-02-19 20:49:30 Etc/GMT";
    "receipt_creation_date_ms" = 1455914970000;
    "receipt_creation_date_pst" = "2016-02-19 12:49:30 America/Los_Angeles";
    "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;
    "request_date" = "2016-02-19 20:49:34 Etc/GMT";
    "request_date_ms" = 1455914974827;
    "request_date_pst" = "2016-02-19 12:49:34 America/Los_Angeles";
    "version_external_identifier" = 0;
};
status = 0;
```

})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `in_app` field is an array so you would have to traverse it

```
for inApp in verifyItem3 {
    // do something with that dictionary, for example 
    print(inApp["product_id"])
}
```

Please note that I wrote this code here, so there might be errors :)

Comment: Thanks! However I had to go 1 more level 'in' to get to the productID. `let verifyItem4 = inApp as! NSDictionary` and `let verifyItem5 = verifyItem4.objectForKey("product_id")`